# Updating ADT plugin in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I have updated my SDK from API level 15 to 17. Now While opening the eclipse i am getting the message to update ADT. When i am trying to update ADT, it is not progressing at all. Please see the attached screen shot.

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 12.01.

Comment: make a try with http (replacing https).

Comment: Try unchecking "Contact all update sites..."

Answer (score 4):

download it from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html in eclipse select install new software from Help menu. select adt plugin and give it a name.

Answer (score 0):

try download it then install it locally http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html gives you steps for offline install or try to uncheck the last option contact all update site during install to find software update